# Powering NX3DV42 switch with 5 V?

Tags: usb, swd

I plan to use the [NX3DV42](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/302/NX3DV42-1841232.pdf) switch from NXP to switch between SWD and USB pins in a nRF53-based design. The goal is to provide USB in a default setting and SWD in an advanced setting by using a switch pin.

[image]

The nRF53 is powered by a battery and I try to avoid powering the switch with 1.8 to remove it from the battery circuit. Instead, the switch should be powered by VBUS, but I´m unsure if I can do it without any issues because the datasheet lists a recommended voltage of 4.3 V. The switch is listed as USB 2.0 dual switch, so I think there shouldn´t be a problem with doing it in this way.

But why is the recommended voltage set to 4.3 V? Other vendors, like Texas Instruments, are doing it in the same way.

Comment: Analog switches can be picky. I can't tell you why this specific one needs it, but I know a lot of analog switches (especially RF ones) have some strange requirements on what specific voltages are used with them.